# EditItem is not allowed for this view при привязке HashSet к DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый день.

В представлении имеется следующий код:

```
<Window ...>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entities, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" Header="Text" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Модель представления:

```
public class MainVm : BaseVm
{
    public ICollection<EntityVm> Entities { get; }

    public MainVm()
    {
        Entities = new HashSet<EntityVm>
        {
            new EntityVm {Text = "раз" },
            new EntityVm {Text = "два" },
        };
    }
}
```

При щелчке по строке `DataGrid` (попытка добавить новый элемент) возникает исключение:

> EditItem is not allowed for this view

Каким образом можно сделать `DataGrid` редактируемым?

Comment: При щелчке по строке какого грида возникает исключение? Приведите код сущности `spr_TypeDevice`.

Comment: Влад, При щелчке по строке ValueGrid.

Comment: @Vlad, добавил код сущности выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы используете `HashSet`. `DataGrid` не умеет добавлять в него элементы. Используйте `List` или `ObservableCollection`.

**UPD**

К ответу на [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578254/datagrid-edition-edititem-is-not-allowed-for-this-view-when-bound-to-a-wpf-da) на en-SO был такой комментарий (далее вольный перевод):

Причина (того, что работает добавление в `List` но не работает в `HashSet`) в том, что привязка `ItemsSource` у `DataGrid` к `HashSet` не генерирует представление коллекции, которое реализует `IEditableCollectionView`. Для `List` генерируется `ListCollectionView`, которая реализует этот интерфейс, потому и работает привязка к `List`.

Comment: большое спасибо! EF всегда по умолчанию использует HashSet?

Comment: @Alex, не знаю, что вы имеете в виду под "по умолчанию". В качестве коллекций можно использовать и List и ObservableCollection. Последнее, кстати, предпочтительнее, если вы хотите выставлять модели для WPF-представления. Вы не против, если я отредактирую ваш вопрос таким образом, что в нем останется только проблема? Возможно, это поможет другим пользователям.

Comment: По умолчанию - я имею ввиду то, что при создании модели мастер автоматически создаёт сущности и свойства используя HashSet. Не против.

Comment: @Alex, не знаю. Мастером не пользовался. Возможно, имеет смысл задать еще один вопрос.